# PHP codeigniter Array to String conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, syntax-error

I am trying to use 1 model for many controller and views as the model has everything in common except for 4 variables , so as to do this i tried to initialize the variables in the model using a `var_setter()` function in model and calling it after the model is loaded in the controller but it shows the following error:

[image]

and the snippets of the model and controller as given below and also the view is working fine :
MODEL:

```
 class Person_model extends CI_Model {
     var $table ='';
     var $column_order = array();
     var $column_search  = array();
     var $order  = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function var_setter($table,$column_order,$column_search,$order){
        $this->$table = $table;
        $this->$column_order = $column_order;
        $this->$column_search = $column_search;
        $this->$order = $order;
      }
?>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Person extends CI_Controller {

    var $table = 'persons';
    var $column_order = array('date_for_contract','contract_contract_no','contract_company_name' ,'contract_created_by','contract_payment_base','contract_billing_cycle','contract_payment_as_per','contract_pay_mode','contract_credit_limit','contract_stax_paid_by','contract_agreed_payment_days',' contract_loading' ,'contract_unloading','contract_reporting_time','contract_packing_mode','contract_location','contract_diesel_rate_on_contract_day','contract_diesel_rate_variation_by_rate','contract_diesel_rate_variation_by_percentage','contract_start_date','contract_end_date','business_relation_start','risk_name','risk_amount','insurance_cover','contract_remark','contract_from','contract_destination','contract_transit_time','contract_mode','load_limit_from','load_limit_to','contract_rate',null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('date_for_contract','contract_contract_no','contract_from','contract_destination','contract_mode'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('person_model','person');
        $this->person->var_setter($this->$table, $this->$column_order, $this->$column_search, $this->$order);

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('person_view');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you point what line is line 23?

Comment: $this->person->var_setter($this->$table, $this->$column_order, $this->$column_search, $this->$order);

Comment: your `$this->$table` should be like `$this->table`

Comment: still the same error @Nikhil

Comment: remove the `$` after `$this`. e.g. `$this->order`

Comment: Can you point line 23, in your **model**, not controller?

Comment: `var $table` Are you using PHP4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Person_model's `var_setter` like this

```
public function var_setter($table,$column_order,$column_search,$order){
    $this->table = $table;
    $this->column_order = $column_order;
    $this->column_search = $column_search;
    $this->order = $order;
  }
```

and then in `Person` controller's construct method

```
$this->person->var_setter($this->table, $this->column_order, $this->column_search, $this->order);
```